# Django SQL query duplicated 2 times

Tags: python, django

Model.py:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    home_team = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    away_team = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class Stat(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    goals = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    assists = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
context_dict = {}
match = Match.objects.get(pk=1)
home_stat = Stat.objects.get(match=match, team=match.home_team)
away_stat = Stat.objects.get(match=match, team=match.away_team)

context_dict['home_stat'] = home_stat
context_dict['away_stat'] = away_stat

return render(request, 'index.html', context_dict)
```

template

```
goals: {{ home_stat.goals }} : {{ away_stat.goals }}
assists: {{ home_stat.assists }} : {{ away_stat.assists }}
```

django-debug-toolbar shows two duplicated queries:
https://sfault-image.b0.upaiyun.com/220/984/2209840587-5a3e5ccccec87_articlex

```
SELECT "myapp_stat"."id", "myapp_stat"."match_id", "myapp_stat"."team", "myapp_stat"."goals", "myapp_stat"."assists" FROM "myapp_stat" WHERE ("myapp_stat"."match_id" = '1' AND "myapp_stat"."team" = '''TeamA''')
  Duplicated 2 times. 
F:\myproject\myapp/views.py in index(11)
  home_stat = Stat.objects.get(match=match, team=match.home_team)

SELECT "myapp_stat"."id", "myapp_stat"."match_id", "myapp_stat"."team", "myapp_stat"."goals", "myapp_stat"."assists" FROM "myapp_stat" WHERE ("myapp_stat"."match_id" = '1' AND "myapp_stat"."team" = '''TeamB''')
  Duplicated 2 times. 

F:\myproject\myapp/views.py in index(12)
away_stat = Stat.objects.get(match=match, team=match.away_team)
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As you have `ForeignKey` in `Stat` to `Match` you can simplify your query using related name stat_set which is provided by default by Django.

   ```
   match.stat_set.filter(...)
   ```
2. You can filter stats by `team__in` lookup. This means that you need one sql query to fetch both stats.

   ```
   both_stats = match.stat_set.filter(team__in=[match.home_team, match.away_team])
   ```
3. What is left is to get them as separate objects.

   ```
   for stat in both_stats:
       if stat.team == match.home_team:
           context_dict['home_stat'] = stat
       elif stat.team == match.away_team:
           context_dict['away_stat'] = stat
   ```
4. Overall this decreases the number of sql queries from 2 to 1 but increases python work.

Answer (score 0):

When doing ORM queries you are able to use double underscore to lookup against fields on the related model. 
Try this:

```
home_stat = Stat.objects.get(match=match)
away_stat = Stat.objects.get(match=match)
```

Comment: NameError: global name 'match__home_team' is not defined. It does not work.

Comment: @Linbin my bad, its only for parameters of course. Anyway bellum already solved this. In your place I'd rather reconsider your db structure.

Comment: i appreciate your help. Should I modify the Stat model with these fields: home_team, away_team, home_goals, home_assists, away_goals, away_assist?

Comment: @Linbin yes, I suppose. Also you can make model Team and relate it with Stat, so then you'll be able to get history of matches for one team.